# Jenkins session timeout configuration

Tags: linux, jenkins, networking, hyperlink, devops

I face 1 issues when my Jenkins session expire.
When time if i open other Jenkins project it's show me ERROR 404 so (Temporary solution is re-login in new tab and refresh old tab) so how can i set this **ERROR 404 URL** to **Jenkins Login URL** ? Please guide me.